# What is the benifit of using jquery protocol less url while referencing jQuery from CDNs?

Tags: jquery

Can we use protocol less URL while referencing jQuery from CDNs and what is the advantage of using protocol less URL while referencing jQuery from CDNs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using protocol less URL while referencing jQuery from CDN as below:

It is quite useful when you are moving from HTTP to HTTPS url. You need to make sure that correct protocol is used for referencing jQuery library as pages served via SSL should contain no references to content served through unencrypted connections.

"protocol-less" URL is the best way to reference third party content that’s available via both HTTP and HTTPS. When a URL’s protocol is omitted, the browser uses the underlying document’s protocol instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use '//' (protocol less) link, the browser will automatically try to make the request with your current protocol.

You could always use https (that will work both on http and https websites), but loading a https resource is slower than loading a http resource because of the encryption and ssl handshakes.